# DbUpdateConcurrencyException on some database instances

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

In my application, I am attempting to update multiple related tables in one API call:

```
Topic | 1:1 | TopicDetails | 1:n | TopicSections
```

Some entries in the sub tables do not exist initially and have to be created on their first use rather than updated. This works on some database instances, and then on others I get the error included at the bottom of this post. Do I have to add entries before I can update them, or is there a way to make this call all encompassing and do both?

If you'd like to see the react component calling this, the JWT token validation method, or require any other information, please let me know. Any help would be lovely.

Service that handles API call:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<Topic>> UpdateTopicDetails(UpdateTopicDetailsRequestDto request, string token)
{
    var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<Topic>() { };

    Topic? topicFromDb = await _db.Topics.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TopicId == request.TopicId);

    TopicDetails? topicDetails = topicFromDb?.Details;

    Researcher researcherFromToken = await GetResearcherFromToken(token);
            
    if (researcherFromToken == null || topicFromDb == null)
    {
        serviceResponse.Data = topicFromDb;
        serviceResponse.Messages = new List<string>() { "Unauthorized 1" };

        return serviceResponse;
    }

    if (topicDetails != null && topicDetails?.ResearcherId != researcherFromToken.ResearcherId)
    {
        serviceResponse.Messages = new List<string>() { "Unauthorized 2" };
        return serviceResponse;
    }

    List<TopicSection> sections = new() { };

    foreach(TopicSection section in request.Sections)
    {
        TopicSection sectionToAdd = new()
                {
                    SectionId = section.SectionId,
                    SectionTitle = section.SectionTitle,
                    SectionBody = section.SectionBody,
                };
        sections.Add(section);
    }

    TopicDetails topicDetailsToAdd = new()
            {
                ResearcherId = researcherFromToken.ResearcherId,
                Researcher = researcherFromToken,
                Sections = sections,
            };

    if (request.TopicDetailsId != null)
        topicDetailsToAdd.TopicDetailsId = (int)request.TopicDetailsId;

    topicFromDb.Details = topicDetailsToAdd;
    _db.Topics.Update(topicFromDb);

    bool success = _db.SaveChanges() > 0;

    if (!success)
    {
        serviceResponse.Messages = new List<string>() { "Failure " };
        return serviceResponse;
    }

    serviceResponse.Data = topicFromDb;
    serviceResponse.Success = true;

    return serviceResponse;
}
```

Error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithRowsAffectedOnly(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__107_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
> at SdeResearch.Api.Services.TopicService.TopicService.UpdateTopicDetails(UpdateTopicDetailsRequestDto request, String token) in C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\SdeResearch\SdeResearch.Api\Services\TopicService\TopicService.cs:line 67
> at SdeResearch.Api.Controllers.TopicController.UpdateTopicDetailsAsync(UpdateTopicDetailsRequestDto request, String Authorization) in C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\SdeResearch\SdeResearch.Api\Controllers\TopicController.cs:line 125
> at lambda_method85(Closure, Object)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Is this exception generated in the line ```bool success = _db.SaveChanges() > 0;``` ?

Comment: @Gehtnet yes it is.